# Should I assign __init__ attributes to class reference or to something like None?

Tags: python

So I have `TerrainManager` class that will store few `TerrainStructure` objects in a list.
I have a method, in the `TerrainStructure` class called `generate_pillar_points()` it's used to set `x, y` values to `TerrainStructure` attributes.

Should I assign the attributes to reference the class? I'm thinking this might be a good approach simply becouse I can look at the attribute and see that will be a `Point` object.
Or should I set the default values to be None or 0, and later, when I call `generate_pillar_points()` to set these attributes to be instance of the `Point` class

I'm asking this question with this in mind:

`a = Cls # reference to Cls`

`a = Cls() # instance of Cls`

Here's the code, I'm sure it will be clearer what I'm trying to ask.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

class TerrainStructure(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # what default values should this points have?
        self.top_left, self.top_right = Point, Point
        self.bottom_left, self.bottom_right = Point, Point

        # picks 4 random points between fixed ranges
        # and assigns them to the above attributes
        self.generate_pillar_points()
```

Comment: You could just not set them at all, and let `generate_pillar_points` set them for the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set them to `None`. That's the only sane option. Or don't assign anything if you *always* call the method that assigns values to them in your constructor.

Setting them to the class itself would be very weird. Also it would not serve any value except making your code harder to debug - imagine an assignment in your method not happening for some reason (maybe accidentally assigning to `self.c` instead of `self.x` because you are clumsy). Then you won't get a nice exception showing that the value is None but something weird or depending on the code no exception at all!

Answer (score -1):

I'd strongly recommend you set these via properties, that validate the values you pass to ensure they are subclasses of Point.

Comment: That's not very pythonic.

Comment: You may say validation is not very pythonic, but the original poster at least implied he was seeking a way to make it clear that these should be assigned objects of a specific type. If you want to do that then properties and raising TypeError's are the way.

Comment: For stuff passed from outside, sure. But why would you validate stuff you set from within your own class?

Comment: The original poster asked about what to set these to in order to know what type of value they take, hence setting them up as properties with validation would do the job more clearly than using None.